# Omitting an argument for a method in a block

Tags: ruby, scala

I wonder, is it possible to do something similar in Ruby to what I can do in Scala or other languages:

```
someCollection.foreach(x => println(x)) // a full version
someCollection.foreach(println) // a short version
```

In Ruby I can do:

```
some_array.each { |x| puts x }
```

So how can I do this?

```
some_array.each { puts }
```

**UPDATE**:

I'm not talking about puts in particular, it just picked it for example. There might be `some_other_method` **which takes one parameter**.

```
some_array.map { some_other_method }
some_array.map(some_other_method) # ???

def some_other_method a
   # ... doing something with a
end
```

Comment: @vgoff it's supposed to know what I want to do the same way it's supposed to know in Scala.

Comment: @vgoff, that's a very interesting philosophical speculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look up the rules for implicit η-expansion in the SLS (§6.26.5), it should be immediately obvious that it relies crucially on static type information and thus cannot possibly work in Ruby.

You *can*, however, *explicitly* obtain a `Method` object via reflection. `Method` objects respond to `to_proc` and like any object that responds to `to_proc` can thus be passed as if they were blocks using the unary prefix `&` operator:

```
some_array.each(&method(:puts))
```

Comment: what is `method` in `some_array.each(&method(:puts))`?

Comment: [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-method) produces a bound `Method` object from the supplied symbol that can then be called without an explicit `self`, allowing the values in your array to be used as the first argument of `puts`.

Comment: Similarly, you can replace the `#each` method with `#map`:

`some_array.map(&method(:puts))`. This more closely resembles the pseudocode you provided in your update.

Comment: @JulienLanglois, but why is it written with the ampersand? it should be just some_array.each(method(:puts)).

Comment: Because `each` expects a block, not a `Method`. The unary prefix `&` operator allows you to pass any object that conforms to the `to_proc` protocol instead of a block.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite like that, unfortunately. You can send a method name to be called on each object, e.g.:

```
some_array.each &:print_myself
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
some_array.each {|x| x.print_myself}
```

But I don't know of a clean (read: built-in) way to do what you're asking for. (Edit: @Jörg's answer does this, though it doesn't really save you any typing. There is no automatic partial function application in Ruby)